# Is ES6 dynamic object property or plain bracket notation being used here?

Tags: javascript

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BFkp8JjLEY&list=PLnHJACx3NwAfRUcuKaYhZ6T5NRIpzgNGJ&index=7) around 16:00 the instructor says dynamic object property syntax is being used (`total[language]`). It seems like it's just regular setting a property on an object using a variable, which here is (destructured from the `repo` object, the current item being iterated over in the reduce method) `language`. Did he make a mistake calling it a dynamic object property or am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: Given [Dynamically access object property using variable](/q/4244896/4642212), this can indeed informally be called “dynamic” property access. This is unrelated to ECMAScript 6, by the way.

Comment: ES6 did introduce [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) in object literals, but as you noted in the question this is just plain bracket notation. (had they used destructruring in assigning the new value they could have used the former `{...total, [language]: ...}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why they called it a dynamic property is because from the perspective of the `total` object - the `language` variable that is being passed in as a key can contain any value during the application runtime, hence hypothetically any property can be accessed at different runs - making it dynamic.

So the instructor was correct as there is no other official term to name a variable that is used as a property accessor.